# Issues with scope in try/catch while using async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, jestjs

My issue is that (seemingly) things are going out of scope, or the scope is being polluted when I enter my `catch` block in the function below:

```
export const getOne = model => async (req, res, next) => {
  let id = req.params.id
  let userId = req.user
  try {
    let item = await model.findOne({ _id: id, createdBy: userId }).exec()
    if (!item) {
      throw new Error('Item not found!')
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({ data: item }) // works perfectly
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: e }) // TypeError: res.status(...).json is not a function
    // also TypeError: next is not a function
    // next(e)
  }
}
```

Interestingly enough, using `res.status(...).end()` in the `catch` block works just fine, but it bothers me that I am not able to send any detail back with the response. According to the Express Documentation for [`res.send()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) and [`res.json`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) I should be able to chain off of `.status()`, which, also interestingly enough, works just fine in the `try` statement above if things are successful - `res.status(200).json(...)` works perfectly.

Also, I tried abstracting the error handling to middleware, [as suggested on the Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html), and through closures, I should still have access to `next` in the `catch` statement, right? Why is that coming back as not a function?

1. Why does `res.status(...).json(...)` work in my `try` but not `catch` block?
2. Why is `next` no longer a function in the `catch` block?

Thanks in advance!

### Edit

This is failing in unit tests, the following code produces the errors described above:

```
describe('getOne', async () => {
  // this test passes
  test('finds by authenticated user and id', async () => {
    expect.assertions(2)

    const user = mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
    const list = await List.create({ name: 'list', createdBy: user })

    const req = {
      params: {
        id: list._id
      },
      user: {
        _id: user
      }
    }

    const res = {
      status(status) {
        expect(status).toBe(200)
        return this
      },
      json(result) {
        expect(result.data._id.toString()).toBe(list._id.toString())
      }
    }

    await getOne(List)(req, res)
  })
  // this test fails
  test('400 if no doc was found', async () => {
    expect.assertions(2)

    const user = mongoose.Types.ObjectId()

    const req = {
      params: {
        id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
      },
      user: {
        _id: user
      }
    }

    const res = {
      status(status) {
        expect(status).toBe(400)
        return this
      },
      end() {
        expect(true).toBe(true)
      }
    }

    await getOne(List)(req, res)
  })
})
```

Comment: Interesting indeed

Comment: very very interesting indeed

Comment: @Arik Added the unit test code used to reproduce these errors.

Comment: @DanStarns Added the unit test code used to reproduce these errors.

Comment: have you tried outside the catch? maybe set a boolean defined outside try/catch and evaluate after or in `finally`

Comment: @Anthony Just tried putting it inside a finally block, and also completely outside (after) the try/catch and I get the same errors as before. `res.status(...).json is not a function`

Comment: You're mocking a `res` object and passing it to your tested code? that's not an Express object to begin with...

Comment: I'm wondering if closure status only gets held onto inside the `try` because that's where the await is? But then that begs the question, why does `res.status().end()` working? Default Nodejs http server response doesn't have a `status` method, that's an express alias.

Comment: @Arik is that a question about mocking? because I don't see any stubs.

Comment: @Arik TBH I didn't write the unit tests, I'm working through an exercise and the goal is to write the controllers in such a way that gets the tests to pass. The tests themselves may be flawed though, I'm honestly not sure. I know very little about jest

Comment: @DanStarns, the OP added the unit tests that pass non-express `res` object.

Comment: Ohhhhhh I'm an idiot. I see what the issue is. The tests are passing through specific functions that I can run on the response object. It's not expecting me to do anything other than `.end()` I was trying to get too fancy. Derp. Thank you so much @Arik !! If you want to write up a quick answer, I'll mark as accepted. Otherwise I'll just delete the question altogether

Comment: @Arik yes I see, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does res.status(...).json(...) work in my try but not catch block?

Seems like you're passing a non-express object that only has `status` & `end` methods when running using the unit testing. That's why it fails to find the `json` method

Comment: Thank you, not sure how I overlooked this!